# Cannot post to WCF REST service with a single string parameter

Tags: c#, http-post, wcf-rest

I'm having problem posting to a WCF REST service with a single string parameter.

My WCF service is decorated as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
IList<CustomerDTO> IServiceCustomers.GetCustomers(string formDataString)
```

My consumer code:

```
string host = "http://localhost:8001";
string path = "WcfRest/GetCustomers";

PostData post = new PostData();
post.Add("Age", txtAge.Text);
post.Add("Group", txtGroup.Text);

IList<CustomerDTO> customers = null;
string recordCount = string.Empty;

var message = new HttpClient().PostMessageAsJson(host, path, post).Result;
customers = message.GetObjectFromMessage<IList<CustomerDTO>>().Result;
dgv.DataSource = customers;
```

Below is the code to post the request:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMessageAsJson(this HttpClient http, string host, string path, PostData postData)
{
    http.BaseAddress = new Uri(host);

    string data = string.Empty;
    if (postData != null)
    {
        data = postData.ToString().ToJsonString();
    }

    StringContent request = new StringContent(data);
    request.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return await http.PostAsync(path, request).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The problem seems to be that the request never reached the WCF server end because on the server side it caught no exceptions.

This is the exception I caught on the client side:

[image: WCF client exception]

Any help is appreciated.

By the way if I change `WebInvoke` from `Post` to `Get` it works.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
The request is able to reach the server but the service method threw no exceptions.

Comment: I think that you may be able to get more info on the server side, because the client receives a reply. Try configuring WCF Tracing. How is your service hosted?

Comment: Then definitely try WCF Tracing

Comment: didn't you miss the `UriTemplate`?

Comment: @Amit, yes the client can find the endpoint

Comment: Reference to resolve  if any one face this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30684222/3877343